# guilty of the illegal sale of houses that were not its to sell in the first place

Tags: possessives, modifiers

> The council appears to be guilty of the illegal sale of houses that were not its **to sell in the first place**. (CGEL,p.471)

I don't get well what role this phrase, *to sell in the first place*, takes. I'm about to incline to think that '*to sell*' is a modifier for '*its*'; '*in the first place*' is an adjunct. Is this right?

Comment: Note that there's a relative clause in there: "The council appears to be guilty of the illegal sale of ***houses(i)*** [that __(i) were not its to sell in the first place]."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the adjuncts are modifying anything, I'd say they were only adding information to explain *illegal* which I think is described as a *causal adjunct*.<sup>[a]</sup>

The original sentence could be written as simply as

> The council appears to be guilty of the illegal sale of houses.

And an adjunct explaining what made the sale illegal is added

> The council appears to be guilty of the illegal sale of houses **that were not its to sell**.

And another adjunct is added to the first adjunct to reinforce that the council did not own the houses it sold and did not check if it did.

> The council appears to be guilty of the illegal sale of houses that were not its to sell **in the first place**.

*In the first place* is adjunct to *that were not it's to sell* and means *This [ownership of the houses] is the first thing the council should have checked before selling them*.

---

a: [Causal Adjunct.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjunct_(grammar)#Semantic_function) from Wikipedia contributors. "Adjunct (grammar)." Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia. Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia, 6 Sep. 2014. Web. 25 Sep. 2014.

> Causal - Causal adjuncts establish the reason for, or purpose of, an action or state.
>   The ladder collapsed because it was old. (reason)